# VS2012 build fails with code 9009

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

My build fails with the following error :

```
Error   21  The command "node ../tools/r.js -o ../tools/build_default.js
node ../tools/r.js -o ../tools/build_intake.js" exited with code 9009.
```

I have the following in the Build Events -> Post-build event command line.

```
node ../tools/r.js -o ../tools/build_default.js
node ../tools/r.js -o ../tools/build_intake.js
```

I also tried giving the whole path like :

```
node C:/inetpub/wwwroot/someABC/Website/tools/r.js -o C:/inetpub/wwwroot/someABC/Website/tools/build_default.js
node C:/inetpub/wwwroot/someABC/Website/tools/r.js -o C:/inetpub/wwwroot/someABC/Website/tools/build_intake.js
```

Still fails with the same error : exited with error code 9009.

Any ideas ??

Thanks !

Comment: Code 9009 means a file couldn't be found. Double-check to make sure node.exe can be found via your PATH environment variable. If you added it manually or installed node while VS was running, you'll have to restart all instances of VS to get it to recognize the change.

Comment: I tried again after restarting and it worked !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Tony I tried again after restarting and it worked !!